# SpriteKit fade out

Tags: ios, swift, animation, sprite-kit

I have two buttons which I want to fade out. When running the following actions nothing happens.

```
    .....
    //Both buttons are SKSpriteNodes

   gameOverRestart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "restart.png")
   gameOverMainMenu = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "harambe.jpg")

   gameOverRestart.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 80, y: self.frame.midY + 50)
   gameOverMainMenu.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX + 80, y: self.frame.midY + 50)

   gameOverRestart.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
   gameOverMainMenu.size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)

   addChild(gameOverRestart)
   addChild(gameOverMainMenu)

   let fade = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0, duration: 1)

   gameOverMainMenu.run(fade)
   gameOverRestart.run(fade)
```

Comment: what are "gameOverMainMenu" and "gameOverRestart"?

Comment: They are SKSpriteNodes that I have added.  I updated my code to make it  more clear.

Comment: add these two line of codes before run action: 
`gameOverMainMenu.zPosition = 1` And `gameOverRestart.zPosition = 0`

Comment: @Mina my problem is not that the buttons do not appear but that no effect occurs. I can see both my buttons but the fade effect doesn't happen which is rather odd since the code is there. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `SKAction.fadeOut(duration: 1)`?

Comment: @Nik Yes I have. I simply cannot understand why nothing is happening. I used the same code on my player's sprite and it worked.

Comment: Try explicitly setting the nodes alpha before you run the action

Comment: @Nik still nothing. I feel the need to mention that before these buttons appear I delete all children but do not think that it matters in this situation.

Comment: Have you tried running a different action on the nodes? Are your nodes paused? Try setting their `paused` to false before you run the actions. Same goes for the scene, and any other parent nodes

Comment: @Nik THANK YOU SO MUCH! I had completely forgotten about setting my view.isPaused = true. You are a life saver

Comment: @Nik in case you can also help me with a problem that just occurred, the animation does happen now but if I click on the buttons before it has finished it restarts the animation.

Comment: @Nik Good solution man, this question is solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that your node and all its parents are not paused. Paused nodes do not react to actions, and are effectively paused (really? I didn't know... :) ). You can unpause nodes like so:

```
node.paused = false
```

Where "node" is the declared name of the node to be unpaused.

Also make sure that your view is not paused:

```
view.paused = false
```

As for your other issue from the comments, try this (it may not be the most efficient but it works):

1. Declare a Boolean value
2. Set it to true before running the action, then reset it to false after running the action.
3. Use this to determine whether the action is currently being run.

The code should look something like this:

```
var running = false

...

let fade = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0, duration: 1)

if running == false {
    running = true
    gameOverRestart.run(fade, completion: { running = false })
}
```

Comment: Always there to save the day!